# Verificar se um número é inteiro, se não for, fazer com que o usuário digite novamente

Tags: c++

A ideia é fazer um programa que solicita ao usuário um numero, verificar se esse numero é real positivo caso contrário, solicita digitar novamente outro número, esse processo pode se repetir inúmeras vezes...

````
            cout<<"Digite um número: "<<endl;
            cin>>number;

            if(number % 2 == 0 ){
                cout<<"O número é real positivo"<<endl;
            } else {
                cout<<"O número não é real positivo, por favor, digite novamente: "<<endl;
            }


            system("pause");
            return 0;```
````

Comment: Olá, existem algumas maneiras de se resolver o seu problema, a mais adequada me parece ser a da resposta do Junior Nascimento, mas como esse parece ser um desafio para iniciantes, imagino que seria válido ver como outras estruturas de repetição funcionam e tentar resolver o mesmo problema com elas também, fazer isso pode te deixar mais preparado para futuros desafios e com certeza agregará conhecimento. Vou deixar um link com um bom artigo sobre o assunto caso tenha interesse: [DevMedia Sobre estruturas de repetição em c](https://www.devmedia.com.br/estrutura-de-repeticao-c/24121)
.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
std::cout << "Digite um número: ";
do{
    std::cin >> number;
    if(number%2 == 0){ 
        std::cout << "O número é real positivo" << std::endl
    }else{
        std::cout << "O número não é real positivo, por favor, digite novamente: ";
while(number%2 == 0);
```

Comment: `while(number%2 == 0)`? Não seria `while(number>0)`? Eu sei que o `number % 2 == 0` já estava na pergunta, mas não acho que estivesse correto.

Comment: eu não quis mudar nada do que ele ja tinha feito. fiquei uns bons minutos pensando se deveria mesmo colocar o do while assim ou então mandar um artigo com todas as estruturas de repetição.

Answer (score 0):

O número inserido pode não ser inteiro, como 0.2. Por isso é preferível usar "doubles" e não "ints". Assim, ficaria:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>    //uma grande biblioteca de funções que inclui tudo o que é necessário
using namespace std;

double number;

int main (){
number=-1;
  while(number<=0){
    cout << "Digite um número: ";
    cin >> number >> endl;
    if(number>0){
      cout<<"O número é real positivo"<<endl;
    }else{
      cout<<"O número não é real positivo, por favor, insira novamente
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```